# xml2js: put parser into a function

Tags: json, node.js, nested-function

I got this code on my NodeJS server:

```
function GetXML() {
    fs.readFile('../slideshow.xml.old', function(err, data) {
        parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
            var json = JSON.stringify(result);
            console.log(json);
            return json;
        });
    });
}
```

The `console.log()` is working well but this is not:

```
.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.end(GetXML());
};
```

It returns `undefined` which is quite logic because functions are nested (I think ?). But I don't know how to make GetXML() returning a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's returning `undefined` because you're trying to execute synchronously an asynchronous task. You have to pass a callback to your `GetXML()` function, like:

```
function GetXML(cb) {
  fs.readFile('../slideshow.xml.old', function(err, data) {
    parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
      var json = JSON.stringify(result);
      cb(json);
    });
  });
}
```

, and call it properly in your `.get` function:

```
.get('/', function(req, res) {
  GetXML(function (json) {
    res.end(json);
  });
};
```

You should take a look at [this article](https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node#callbacks) that explains how `callbacks` work in node.js.

Answer (score 0):

"GetXML" is not returning a value. It can be change to:

```
function GetXML() {
    return fs.readFile('../slideshow.xml.old', function(err, data) {
        parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
            var json = JSON.stringify(result);
            console.log(json);
            return json;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your solution is not working :( `console_log(json)` is working but the function is still returning `undefined`.